# string list max value python

Tags: python, list

how to check from a python string list which is the largest item and copy it to another list.
i was trying this.  but i dosnt Works.

```
cad_1 = ['hello', 'hello', 'ewe', 'uwu']
cad_final = {i,j for i,j in Cad_1 if len(i)>=len(j)}
print(cad_final);
```

Comment: This will produce a `NameError` before even getting to the second line... the second line is a set comprehension and you can't loop through a list like that anyway. If you want help you need to clarify exactly what the error is.

Comment: @PanBasic you want all longest strings (both "hello"s) or only one?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Are `hello`, `ewe`, and `uwu` variables or string? Can you clarify what do you mean by largest? Largest value? Longest string? By alphabetical order?

Comment: Specify *"doesn't work"*. What is your expected output, and what is your actual output? As it stands, this code doesn't run.

Answer (score 0):

You can first create a dictionary with the respective string length:

```
my_length_list = {i:len(i) for i in my_list}
```

and then get the largest element by

```
import operator

max_string_len = max(my_length_list.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1))[0]
```

and write this value in another list

```
max_string_list = [max_string_len]
```

Comment: or `max(my_list, key=len)`.

Comment: this is simples one!

Comment: Ah thank you, I did not know this :) Fairly simply like this